# Calculate distance between user location and fixed location

Tags: typescript, react-native

I am trying to calculate the distance between user's current location and specific location. In other words, I need the distance required for the user from their current location to the specific location.

Requirements:

- I need to show user current location (DONE)
- Use a location (in my case (24.41913107517948, 54.43699913714186) and put a marker on that location (DONE)
- If the user current location is inside the radius, show success message, if the user current location is outside the radius, show error message with the required distance to the green radius.

```
const location = {
    latitude: 24.41913107517948,
    longitude: 54.43699913714186,
    latitudeDelta: 0.09,
    longitudeDelta: 0.035
  }


const [loc, setLoc] = useState({
    latitudeDelta: 24.41913107517948,
    longitudeDelta:  54.43699913714186,
});

<MapView
    style={mapStyles}
    mapType='hybrid'
    provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
    region={location}
  >

<MapView.Circle
                        key = { (loc.latitudeDelta + loc.longitudeDelta).toString() }
                        center = { {
                            latitude: loc.latitudeDelta,
                            longitude: loc.longitudeDelta
                        } }
                        radius = { radius }
                        strokeWidth = { 1 }
                        strokeColor = { '#7fff00' }
                        fillColor = { 'rgba(0,238,0,0.5)' }
                />
        
<Marker 

coordinate = {{latitude: 24.41913107517948,longitude: 54.43699913714186}}
         pinColor = {"red"} // any color
         />

</MapView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you know about geolib and getDistance? If not check it out. [Here](https://github.com/manuelbieh/geolib#readme) is github link.